# Have I correctly proved this limit?

Tags: limits, proof-verification

First of all, I'm defining this limit as follows:

Definition: If, given any sequence $(x_n)$ in $\Bbb{R}-0$ such that $x_n \to 0, f(x_n)\to \infty,$ then $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=\infty$.

Claim: $\lim_{x \to 0} [\frac{1}{x^2}]=\infty.$

Proof: Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\Bbb{R}-0$ such that $x_n \to 0$.
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.
We must show that $[f(x_n) \to \infty \iff$ given any $K \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $N_2 \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that for all $n \geq N_2, f(x_n)>K]$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} K>0}$

Let $K \in \mathbb{R^+}$ be given.
Since $x_n \to 0,$ there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that, for all $n \geq N_1$, $| x_n -0| <\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}$

Then, for all $n \geq N, f(x_n)=\underbrace{\frac{1}{x_n^2}>K}_{\text{since }x_n<\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}} \ \text{for all} \ n \geq N},$ hence $f(x_n) \to \infty.$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} K \leq 0}$

Now, let $K' \in [\mathbb{R^-} \cup \{0\}]$ be given.

Then, for all $n \geq N$, $f(x_n)=\frac{1}{x_n^2} >0\geq K' \begin{cases} \text{since} &K' \leq 0 \ \text{by definition} \\ 
 \end{cases} $, hence, for all $n \geq N$, $f(x_n)>K'$ **for all** $K'<0$.

Hence, given any $K$ (positive, negative or $0$), given **any** sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ for which $x_n \to 0, f(x_n)>K.$

Thanks

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: Yep. And I use sequential continuity for my definition of continuity- i.e. $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=L$ if, given any sequence $x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}-\{a\}$ for which $x_n \to a, f(x_n) \to L$.

Comment: @alexqwx Why you make the case $K=0$ and $K<0$? Is enough with the case $K>0$. And your proof looks right.

Comment: In fact, $f(x_n)>0$ for all $n$ then trivially $f(x_n)> K$ if $K\leq 0$.

Comment: Ok, in retrospect, I suppose I didn't have to do if for $K=0$, but I did it for $K<0$, since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}$ is undefined (in $\mathbb{R}$) for $K<0$.

Comment: @LuisValerin - RE your last comment- how so?

Comment: As @Ishfaaq say, is sufficient to prove the property for a $K>0$ arbitrary (the case $K\leq 0$) is not necessary. Then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}$ is well define. Sorry i don't understand your doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove $y_n \to \infty$ it suffices to pick an arbitrary **positive** value $K$ and to prove that for sufficiently large $n$, $y_n \gt K$. There is no need to differentiate between $K \le 0$ and $K \gt 0$. If for formality $K \le 0$ since you have proven the positive case there are values in the sequence greater than $1$ and hence greater than your negative number.

So suppose $(x_n)$ is a sequence that tends to $0$. Choose $0 \lt \epsilon \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt K}$. There is $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $n \ge N \implies |x| \lt \epsilon \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt K} \implies x^2 \lt \frac{1}{K} \implies \frac{1}{K} \lt \frac{1}{x^2}$ since $x \neq 0$. We have just shown that there is $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $n \ge N \implies |f(x_n)| = f(x_n) \gt K$ for an arbitrary $K \gt 0$ which proves that $\lim f(x_n) = \infty$.

$\mathscr {Q.E.D.}$